# reading an xml file in C# using CsQuery

Tags: c#, csquery

```
using CsQuery;       
namespace CSQuery    
{
    class Program  
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)       
        {
            var dom = CQ.Create(/*I am not sure what goes here*/);
            //Not sure if this is the correct setup as well
            CQ mf = dom["MANUFACTURER"];
            CQ md = dom["MODEL"];       
            Console.WriteLine(mf);
            Console.WriteLine(md);
            Console.ReadKey();       
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

--------------------------------------------------------
PARTS:
Title:   Computer Parts 

    <ITEM>Motherboard</ITEM>
    <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
    <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
    <COST> 123.00</COST>
    <ITEM>Video Card</ITEM>
    <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER>
    <MODEL>All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
    <COST>160.00</COST>
    <ITEM>  Monitor </ITEM>
    <MANUFACTURER>LG Electronics</MANUFACTURER>
    <MODEL> 995E</MODEL>
    <COST> 290.00</COST>
  </PART></PARTS>
```

Above is my code I have written so far I am trying to extract the MANUFACTURER and MODEL from the sample given xml code. When I compile I get an error message saying source can not be found and I think it may be a problem with my setup and I am unclear on what exactly is suppose to go into my CQ.Create() as a parameter(I tried putting in the exact parts.xml file but that didn't help).

Comment: Post the exact error you're getting.
Also your xml looks weird. I would have though it would look more like 
`<ITEM description ="Motherboard">
   <MANUFACTURER>ASUS</MANUFACTURER>
   <MODEL>P3B-F</MODEL>
   <COST> 123.00</COST>
</ITEM>
<ITEM description="Video Card">
   <MANUFACTURER>ATI</MANUFACTURER> 
   <MODEL>All-in-Wonder Pro</MODEL>
   <COST>160.00</COST>
</ITEM>`

Comment: Side note: consider reading XML with regular XML APIs lile LINQ-to-XML or XmlDocument as generally you'll get more samples / more people to help you with problems.

Comment: Thanks I was able to figure it out

Comment: What was the solution, @NickJ?